# jQuery .append executes multiple times on single object

Tags: php, jquery

I want to use jQuery .append to insert a div into an another parent div which is part of a list element and consists of one dynamically created form field. Although the parent class contains only one object (i.e. text field) and exists only once within the whole document, .append adds the div six times. It works finde in JSfiddle but not on my local code (Magento form). Why is that? Could it be related to the dynamical creation of the parent class?

PHP

```
$input_name     = $this->getInputName();
$input_id       = $this->getInputId();
$input_value    = $this->getValue();
$input_class    = $this->getInputClass();
$label          = $this->getLabel();

<div class="input-box <?php echo $input_id;?>">
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $input_name;?>" id="<?php echo $input_id;?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($input_value) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__($label); ?>" class="<?php echo $input_class;?>" />
</div>
```

with jQuery

```
$(".input-box.billing_postcode") .append("<div>My Link</div>")
```

always leads to the follwing HTML

```
<li>
<div class="input-box billing_postcode">
<input id="billing_postcode" class=" input-text required-entry absolute-advice " type="text" title="ZIP" value="" name="billing[postcode]">
<div>My Link</div>
<div>My Link</div>
<div>My Link</div>
<div>My Link</div>
<div>My Link</div>
<div>My Link</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code is being ran multiple times. Where is it being ran? what is executing it? a change event? click event?

Comment: $(".input-box") .append("<div>My Link</div>") instead of $(".input-box.billing_postcode") .append("<div>My Link</div>") will do and put your jquery code outside loop

Comment: @KevinB: It is a module which modifies the default checkout form which I am trying to customize, I will take a deeper look into the code and see if I can find answers to your questions.

Comment: @AshirvadSingh Yes this will put it out of the loop but will apply the link to all other divs like input-box shipping form, payment form etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix:

```
var $element = $(".input-box.billing_postcode");
if($('.foo', $element).length == 0) {
    $element.append('<div class="foo">My Link</div>');
}
```